# Change the color of ElevatedButton

Tags: flutter

How can I change the background color of the `ElevatedButton`?

```
child: ElevatedButton(                 
                  onPressed: (){},
                  child: Text('Get Started', 
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 20.0,
                  ),),
                ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a ButtonStyle!

```
ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: onPressed, 
          child: child, 
          style: ButtonStyle(backgroundColor: color),
        )
```

It's also got many other options besides backgroundColor if you want to explore it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using style as below

```
    ElevatedButton(
       onPressed: onPressed,
       child: child,
       style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
         backgroundColor: Colors.black
     )
    )
```